# J2ME communicating with MS-SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, web-services, java-me

I am trying to create an integrated project in which I can update MS-SQL's database value using J2ME's application.

But I need more resources/links that let me fully understand how to go about writing implementation for this.

These are the few question in which I've got in mind.

1. How do I update the data that I've got from J2ME into MSSQL 2005?
2. How do I retrieve and view the updated value from the database?
3. How do I send sms to the J2ME's application, as the other application of mine need to send an 'alert' to the j2me app.

Answer (score 2):

Short of writing your own ODBC library for J2ME, I would suggest you look at writing a web service layer over your database which the J2ME application can communicate with over HTTP.